# Como ordenar um array com critérios de desempate caso um dos campos seja igual

Tags: javascript

Como eu comparo somente o número de gols dos primeiros colocados se eles tiverem o mesmo número de pontos, existe um modo de fazer isso comparando itens em arrays diferentes?

Eu olhei a resposta do exercicio e depois do `else` ele colocou:
Minha dúvida é que como ele está dentro de um IF ele toda rodada* vai somar o número de gols com o número de pontos, não vejo a lógica de somar os dois para definir o primeiro colocado, um time pode perder de 7x6 e fazer 6 pontos e um time ganhar de 1x0 e fazer 4 pontos.

```
timesRj[anfitriao][3] = (timesRj[anfitriao][1] + timesRj[anfitriao][2]);
timesRj[convidado][3]= (timesRj[convidado][1]) + timesRj[convidado][2];           

//ordem por número de pontos
timesRj.sort((a,b) => a[3] - b[3]);



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport">
    <title>Curso Javascript</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <h1>Javascript Start</h1>

    
    <script>


//Times para o campeonato

let timesRj = [["Flamengo",0,0],["Fluminense",0,0],["Botafogo",0,0],["Vasco",0,0], ["America", 0,0]];


//Campeonato Carioca

//total de times

let totalTimesRj = timesRj.length;

for(let anfitriao = 0; anfitriao < totalTimesRj; anfitriao++){
    for(let convidado = 0; convidado < totalTimesRj; convidado++){

        if(anfitriao !== convidado){

            let limiteGols = Math.round(Math.random()* 8);
            let golsAnfitriao = Math.round(Math.random() * limiteGols);
            let golsConvidado = Math.round(Math.random() * limiteGols);
            timesRj[anfitriao][2] += golsAnfitriao;
            timesRj[convidado][2] += golsConvidado;

            let time1 = `${timesRj[anfitriao][0]}`;
            let time2 = `${timesRj[convidado][0]}`;

            console.log(`Jogo: ${time1} ${golsAnfitriao} X ${time2} ${golsConvidado}`);

            //Atribui pontuação para os times

            if(golsAnfitriao > golsConvidado){
                timesRj[anfitriao][1] += 3;

            }
            else if(golsConvidado > golsAnfitriao){
                timesRj[convidado][1] += 3;

            }
            else{
                timesRj[anfitriao][1] +=1;
                timesRj[convidado][1] +=1;
            }
            }
            }
            }

           let campeaoNome =  `${timesRj[totalTimesRj -1][0]}`;
        //ordem por número de pontos
        timesRj.sort((a,b) => a[1] - b[1]);
        alert(timesRj[totalTimesRj - 1] [0]);

        if(timesRj[totalTimesRj - 1][1] == timesRj[totalTimesRj - 2][1] && timesRj[totalTimesRj - 1][2] < timesRj[totalTimesRj - 2][2]){
            campeaoNome =  `${timesRj[totalTimesRj -2][0]}`;
        }
        else{
            campeaoNome =  `${timesRj[totalTimesRj -1][0]}`;
        }


        //Exibe a tabela do campeonato

        alert(`${campeaoNome}`);

        //Exibe o campeão



        let campeaoPontos = `${timesRj[totalTimesRj - 1] [1]}`;
        let gols = `${timesRj[totalTimesRj - 1] [2]}`;
        
        console.log(`O campeão foi o ${campeaoNome} com ${campeaoPontos} pontos e ${gols} gols.`);

        alert(timesRj);
       


    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

De fato essa lógica de somar os gols com os pontos está furada. Pode até funcionar em muitos casos (já que **em tese** um time que ganhou mais jogos, geralmente fez mais gols que os demais), mas sabemos que nem sempre é assim.

É possível, por exemplo, que o time A tenha perdido um jogo sem marcar gols, e ganhado 4 jogos de goleada (portanto, fez 12 pontos e digamos que uns 20 gols), enquanto o time B ganhou 5 jogos de 1 x 0 (fazendo portanto 15 pontos e 5 gols). Se usar essa lógica furada de somar gols com pontos, o time A será considerado campeão, mas se o critério é quem fez mais pontos, e os gols são apenas para desempate, então o time B deveria ser o campeão.

Sendo assim, a maneira correta de fazer seria:

- esqueça essa lógica furada de somar gols com pontos, então não precisa dessas linhas:

  ```js
  timesRj[anfitriao][3] = (timesRj[anfitriao][1] + timesRj[anfitriao][2]);
  timesRj[convidado][3] = (timesRj[convidado][1]) + timesRj[convidado][2];
  ```
- a função de ordenação tem que implementar a regra correta:

  ```js
  function comparaPontosGols(a, b) {
      // primeiro compara pontos
      let cmp = a[1] - b[1];
      if (cmp == 0) { // somente se pontuação é igual, compara gols
          cmp = a[2] - b[2];
      }
      return cmp;
  }

  // ordena segundo o critério acima
  timesRj.sort(comparaPontosGols);
  // Exibe o campeão (usar destructuring assignment para obter os dados)
  let [ campeaoNome, campeaoPontos, campeaoGols ] = timesRj[timesRj.length - 1];
  console.log(`O campeão foi o ${campeaoNome} com ${campeaoPontos} pontos e ${campeaoGols} gols.`);
  ```

Ou seja, eu só comparo os gols se a pontuação for igual.

E como o time é representado por um array com 3 elementos, eu posso usar o [*destructuring assingment*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) para obter os valores diretamente, um em cada variável.